# Cannot connect to Oracle server

Tags: oracle, database-connection

I have a Oracle server which can be accessed locally (i.e. from the computer where Oracle installed) using SQLPlus and default port 1521.

From a client computer, I can access shared folders on that server, but I cannot access the oracle database using SQLPlus or SQL Developer. "IO Error: The network Adapter could not establish the connection."

I am sure that there are problems on the Oracle server, because I can access other similar Oracle servers from the same client.

There is no problem with network connection as well.

Tnsnames.ora files are also OK. Three oracle services are started (same as other similar Oracle servers): listener, DBConsole and Service.

All are Windows systems.

How can I figure it out?

**P.S.:**
  No firewall on server;
  tnsping is OK.

Comment: Are there any firewalls between you and the server ? also have you tried to tnsping the database?

Comment: tnsping from the _client_ is OK?

Comment: Yes, tnsping from the client is OK.

Comment: Something must be wrong then between listener and database server then. Are you using MTS (Multi threaded server?). Does listener.log tell you something?

Comment: if the tns entry is using a machine name could you confirm the machine name is pointing to the correct machine/ip.

Comment: and that it's fully qualified to make sure the server can do a reverse lookup.

Comment: I am not using MTS. I think the listener.ora is wrong. The host name in listener.ora is not correct. If I correct it, must I restart Oracle server? I cannot restart it now.

Comment: No need to restart the database instance. Restart listener and wait until database is serviced by the listener by checking "lsnrctl status" or do a "alter system register" in the database.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I corrected listener.ora, run "alter system register" twice, restart listener service twice, in between i found an TNS-12505 error in listener log file, but finally it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the listener on the server or tnsnames.ora on client is the problem. When connecting from the server the sql*net protocol is bypassed. 
On server run :

```
c:\lsnrctl status
```

and check if database is serviced by the listener and check if parameters are the same as in tnsnames.ora, use fully qualified host names.

**EDIT**
Check

c:\lsnrctl services

Answer (score -2):

May be your firewall block your port. you can enable this by changing firewall setting.
This is windows 7 configuration to access port
Control panel->system and security->windows firewall->advanced setting->In bound rules-> new Rule(On right hand side)-> select port option with value as  "1521" -> next next....