# Cannot connect to OracleDB (Port 1521), except Tomcat7.exe

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tomcat7

**Environment:**

- Windows Server 2019 x64 with Oracle DB installation.
- IPv4: 192.168.0.18
- ODB Port: 1521

I found `Tomcat7.exe` is `ESTABLISHED` with `192.168.0.18:1521` from TCPViewer.exe.
But any application cannot connect to `192.168.0.18:1521`.
Test network connection invalid, checked it from powershell.

Powershell Command Line: `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 192.168.0.18 -Port 1521`
Result: `Fail`

I'm new to OracleDB. I've already checked Windows and Ext Network firewall rules, but no limitation for this connection.

**Questions:**

1. Why I cannot connect to the Oracle server using `sqlplus.exe`?
2. Is there a configuration to allow or block specific IP addresses (or applications)?

Comment: firewall setting?

Comment: Already I checked the rules on Windows firewall, but no problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774889/cannot-connect-to-oracle-server I recommend to read this post.